# Debian 10: No microphone access on Chromium based browsers

Tags: debian, microphone, chrome

After upgrading from Debian Stretch to Debian Buster [microphone access](https://test.webrtc.org/) stopped working on all the Chromium based browsers. I've tested with Chromium, Chrome, Iridium and Vivaldi. At the same time Firefox works fine.

See a short video capture of what happens [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GVu-80ITJXnJ_stz1QzoL0d7BbfuLROv/view).

How can I get microphone access back on Chromium based browsers?

```
[0] mypc<u0>:~>arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices **** card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3235 Analog [ALC3235 Analog]   Subdevices: 1/1  
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card 2: Dock [WD15 Dock], device 0: USB
Audio [USB Audio]   Subdevices: 1/1   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 card
3: Headset [Logitech USB Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]  
Subdevices: 1/1   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


[0] mypc<u0>:~>uname -a 
Linux mypc 4.19.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.37-5+deb10u1 (2019-07-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

PS. This message was posted also to [Debian forum](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=142983).

Comment: Could you add some details in your question about your hardware, especially results of commands such as `pacmd list-sources`, `arecord -l`, `uname -a` for example? For the record, my main workstation went through the same process and doing the same procedure you did yield a different result (it works).

Comment: See the command results [here](https://paste.debian.net/plainh/e4b63859).

Comment: What is the PulseAudio input you are trying to use? Did you try them all?

Comment: How can I choose input device for Chromium? When I try to [access microphone with Firefox](https://test.webrtc.org/), FF appears in Xfce Volume Control → Recording tab and I can choose an input device for it. Also FF itself has a dialog for choosing an input device. When I try to access microphone with Chromium it does not appear in the Xfce Volume Control → Recording tab and I can't choose the input device.

Comment: The easiest would be to use this in your Chromium address bar: [chrome://settings/content/microphone](chrome://settings/content/microphone). In the drop down box, you will have a list of choices for the microphone input. Otherwise, like you said, through your desktop environment sound settings usually (maybe not anymore in XFCE? It has been a while since I used it for the last time).

Comment: There's no drop down box in `chrome://settings/content/microphone`. See [the screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/IrBdbaY.png).

Comment: This could be the issue. :) My Chromium version is 73.0.3683.75 and is the latest version from the `stable` branch. What's yours?

Comment: `about:` `73.0.3683.75 (Developer Build) built on Debian buster/sid, running on Debian 10.0 (64-bit)`

Comment: I created a new test user and logged in. Chromium mic access works fine! The problem must be in my personal settings. However, deleting ~/.config/chromium does not help.

Comment: You should check the differences between the two users; maybe you've identified a bug or at least a major setting change.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem : no more microphone on Chromium (and Firefox too).

```
# uname -a
Linux debian 5.4.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.4.13-1~bpo10+1 (2020-02-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# arecord -l
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels CAPTURE ****
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

After setting up in the Xfce Volume Control : Configuration -> Audio interne -> was on : Sortie stéréo analogique, I had set to : Duplex stéréo analogique, then I get :

```
# arecord -l
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels CAPTURE ****
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 0/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
```

and now output audio and microphone input work fine on both Chromium and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If the microphone is working in other browser, you were likely hit by https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=884887.

Check for `"audio_capture_enabled":false`, either in `/etc/chromium/master_preferences` or `~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`. (The directory may differ for non-chromium?)

Changing this to true (kill the browser first, otherwise it will just ignore it) fixed this for me.